# How to create sequence for foreign key in oracle?

Tags: c#, oracle

I have one table Employees with columns ID number(2) primary key, Name varchar2(20) not null, PID number(2) not null.

PID has foreign key from the ID which is in the same table.

I want to create Combo Box which contains all values from the column Name. Also,  when I select certain value from the column Name, after I clicked on button, that also have to create value for PID in table Employees.

I tried to insert auto_increment with sequence for PID, but it wasn't work, because it's not a primary key.

So, I don't have any idea how to solve this step. Because it's so complicated when you have all that columns in one table.

Comment: A foreign key value should already exist as a (primary) key when you insert it as a foreign key, so you can never automatically create a sequence for a foreign key. It is quite unclear what you are trying to accomplish. After clicking on a name, _where_ do you expect a PID to be created? In a new record, or do you want to update an existing record? In any case, I would expect that PID to be the ID value belonging to the selected name.

Answer (score 0):

Is the ID value always equal to the PID ?

If yes, I guess you have a database design issue.

If not, you can try to use the sequence of the ID column.

Comment: Then I guess you have to write 2 SQL statements to assign the created PID
I think you also need to clarify your question